# Prevent Automatic Creation of QuoteLineItems

Tags: quote, quotelineitem

When you go to create a Quote, Salesforce automatically grabs the Products from the Opportunity and creates QuoteLineItems. Is there any way to override this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a way to do this using the boolean Quote field CanCreateQuoteLineItems.  This field is marked as not used in the documentation.

```
CanCreateQuoteLineItems 
    Type
        boolean
    Properties
        Create, Defaulted on create, Group
    Description
        This field is not used.
```

I do not fully know what your use case is, but using a Flow would be the easiest way to override this standard process in favor of a simpler approach (create new Quote via Flow only mapping relevant Opportunity fields).